# The role of the word "but"

Tags: meaning

What does *but* mean in the following sentence taken from Bertrand Russell's *Problems of Philosophy*?

> Such questions are bewildering, and it is difficult to know that even the strangest hypotheses may not be true. Thus our familiar table, which has roused **but** the slightest thoughts in us hitherto, has become a problem full of surprising possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word [**but**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/but), which you almost exclusively see used only as a conjunction, can also be an adverb meaning *no more than* or *only*. And it looks like such is the case with your quote here:

> Such questions are bewildering, and it is difficult to know that even the strangest hypotheses may not be true. Thus our familiar table, which has roused **only** the slightest thoughts in us hitherto, has become a problem full of surprising possibilities.